# CMake syntax highligh and helper in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, cmake, syntax-highlighting, clion

`CLion` has very good support of `CMake`. It highlights syntax and provides suggestions. `Android studio` lacks this feature. Is there a way to enable/add it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the same problem a few month ago. As Cinder Biscuits mentioned, there was no such plugin found, except not working prototype [CMaker](https://github.com/dubrousky/CMaker). So, I just make my own plugin: [CMake plugin for IntelliJ Idea CE and Android Studio](https://github.com/ArtsiomCh/CMake)

Work is still in progress. The plugin is inspired and based on CMaker by Aliaksandr Dubrouski.

CMake Syntax from cmake.org is mostly implemented. Commands, Variables, Properties, and Operators was taken from vim CMake support pluging.

There are few known syntax highlights bugs, mostly around $ symbol, because it's used to recognize Variable references in arguments. But those bugs could be reproduced mostly on synthetic tests while real CMakeLists.txt files shown correctly.

In case you don't need such a detailed highlight (i.e. it looks too motley) you can always change colors at plugin settings.

[image: CMake plugin for IntelliJ Idea CE and Android Studio]

Answer (score 1):

There is not for Android Studio. Your best alternative if you like Clion's UI would be to use Intellij IDEA with the Android and CMake plugins for one a single IDE experience.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/prerequisites-for-android-development.html